MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline: How to Accumulate Data from an Inner Array
I have a dataset in MongoDB that contains array data for each state, each of which has it's own inner array of zip codes.  Here is a simplified example of the structure:
[
  {
    data: { 
      name: 'Alabama',
      zip_codes: [
        {
          id: 00000,
          population: 10
        },
        {
          id: 00001,
          population: 20,
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      name: 'Alaska',
      zip_codes: [
        {
          id: 10000,
          population: 5,
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
  ...
]

My objective is to create a MongoDB view of just the zip code data.  I want this (retaining the order from the original document):
zip_codes: [
  {
    id: 00000,
    population: 10
  },
  {
    id: 00001,
    population: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 10000,
    population: 5,
  },
  ...
]

I'm fairly new to MongoDB and am looking at the aggregation pipeline, particularly group and projection operations so far, but have not quite come across a way to do this.  To all the Mongo experts out there, is there a pipeline I can build that will accomplish this?
I've tried $match and $project stages but couldn't quite find something for this problem.  I feel like this is solvable with Mongo but I'm too inexperienced.  Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Simply $unwind the data.zip_codes field. $replaceRoot with the object to make it as the root document. The order of the documents will remain intact as long as you do not perform any sorting.
db.runCommand( { create: "zipCodeView", viewOn: "zipCodes", pipeline: [
  {
    "$unwind": "$data.zip_codes"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data.zip_codes"
    }
  }
]} )

Mongo Playground

Your expected output does not indicate clearly that do you want to put all the subdocuments into an array, but I will against that idea, since that may breach MongoDB 16MB document size limit if the total count of documents is large.
